# Ajax works in IE and Edge but not Firefox when form is submitted using bootstrap 4 template

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to validate form Input field and run Ajax code in a login page using a bootstrap 4 template (called Deskapp) before the form is submitted. There are only two input fields userid and password.

Most of the code has been provided by the template, i have just adjusted the code to my need. The code works fine in IE and Edge, but the Ajax code does not work in Firefox.

```
 // html code
<div class="login-wrap customscroll d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap justify-content-center pd-20">
    <div class="login-box bg-white box-shadow pd-30 border-radius-5">
        <img src="vendors/images/login-img.png" alt="login" class="login-img">
        <h2 class="text-center mb-30">Login</h2>
        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="input-group custom input-group-lg">
                <input class="form-control" name="userid" type="number" placeholder="userid" required="required">
                <div class="input-group-append custom input-tip-div" class="input-tip-div">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> <?php echo REQUIRED.NUMBERS;?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group custom input-group-lg">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="**********">
                <div class="input-group-append custom">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="send" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign In">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

 // script code

(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() == false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                } 
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"user/logindo.php",
                    data: $("#send").closest("form").serialize(),       
                    success:function (data) {
                        alert ("This is the Data from Json: "+data);
                    }
                });

            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})();
```

I expect the form input field validate first, then execute the  Ajax code and finally the form should be submitted.

The actual result in Firefox, the two input field validates correctly, then Firefox ignores the Ajax code and submits the form, but IE and Edge browsers runs smoothly by executing all the code as expected. Thank You in Advance

Comment: It's most likely because `event.preventDefault();` is only called if the validation fails. That part prevents the browser from navigating like a normal form submit. Most likely IE and Edge actually aren't working (validation returns false) and that code is triggered, which makes it look like it works. Just add `console.log('validation failed');` underneath `event.stopPropagation();` and open your browser console to check if that's the case. Then fix the code by turning the `if()` statement into an `if() {} else {}`.

Comment: @icecub i just tried leaving the input field blank and also i entered incorrect data into the input field, when i pressed submit button, all 3 browsers console.log showed 'validation failed' and the form was not submitted

Comment: i just turned the `if()` Statement into an `if() {} else {}`. and i place all the Ajax code inside the `else` statement. But i did not include the `form.classList.add('was-validated');` in the `else` statement. i tried to do `console.log('validation success')` inside the `else` statement, guess what none of the 3 browsers showed the  `('validation success')` when correct data was entered into the input field, strangely though IE and Edge did execute the Ajax code but Firefox failed.